# Parsing remote xml in php with simpleXML

Tags: php, xml

I have the following xml

```
<rss>
<channel>   
<item><title><![CDATA[bla]]></title><description><![CDATA[desc1]]></description><link>blah</link></item>
<item><title><![CDATA[bleh]]></title><description><![CDATA[desc2]]></description><link>blahhh</link></item>
</rss>
</channel>
```

I want to get all the text in "description" however it is surrounded by CDATA.I thought the following would work

```
$xmlurl = file_get_contents('http://anxmlfile.xml');    
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlurl, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

foreach ($xml->item as $item) {
   echo $item->description->innertext;
}
```

I was expecting the scrript to echo "desc1desc2", however nothing is ever echo'd.

**UPDATE*

Here is some full code (I am making an rss reader)

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('http://www.skysports.com/rss/0,20514,11661,00.xml', LIBXML_NOCDATA, true);


/* For each <character> node, we echo a separate <name>. */
foreach ($xml->item as $item) {
   echo (string)$item->description;
}
```

Comment: Just a minor improvement: The loading of the xml can be achieved using ``$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('http://anxmlfile.xml', LIBXML_NOCDATA, true);``

Comment: Thank you I have adjusted my code to include this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SimpleXML is kind of tricky, you need to explicitly typecast everything,

`echo (string)$item->description;`

should work.

**EDIT:** also, what's with the "innertext"? Cut that out. And another thing, in that XML, is the content wrapped in some root node, such as `<items>`? If not, foreach won't work.

**EDIT2:** okay, after the edited question, it becomes clearer, you're doing the iteration wrong, leaving out `<channel>`. This will work:

```
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
   echo (string)$item->description;
}
```

Comment: Hi cypher, there is a root node "rss" and the parent node of item is "channel". I have edited my post with a replicatable piece of code

Comment: I love you and I want to have your babies.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work:

```
echo $item->description
```

Leaving the innertext out.